# How to remove grid lines to distinguish between lattice sites using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, matrix, gridview, mathematical-lattices

The result for certain calculations when drawn using python matshow

[image: gives the figure as].

Is there any way to draw lines

[image: like a border between the various colors like in this]

like a border between the various colors like in this figure?
This is a grid n X n that looks like this initially.

[image: that looks like this initially]

Each square has 4 small squares(lattices) within it. i.e in the case of the first square, it has (0,0), (1,0), (0,1) and (1,1) indices occupied by the same number say 0 and the next square has (0,3), (0,3), (1,3) and (1,3) indices occupied by a different number say 1.

This is resulting in a different color. After subjecting it to some mathematical operations I got the first image. Now I want to distinguish between these colors as in figure 2. Is there a way to do this? Any leads would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over each cell in the final grid to compare its color with its `N, S, E, W` neighbors, and draw a line segment corresponding to the border, when the condition is met, and not when the cells share the same color.

I would have provided a small sample code, but you did not explain how your cells and grids are represented; however, this is rather straightforward code that you can probably write.